# PHP curly braces inside if - how is it possible?

Tags: php

The following PHP code works. It displays `1`:

```
<?php
if (!is_null(null){1 == 2}{false}{$b = 323}) {
    echo 1;
}
```

I am running it on PHP 7.2.34.

The question is: what exactly does the code do and why does it work? How does PHP interpret it? It seems that the things in the curly braces are conditions, but how are they connected (with `and` or `or`)?

Comment: 'It does work' but throws 3 errors! eg "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool" - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4ArM01BQzGzOD6vNCdHA0RoVhsq2NoqGNVWpyXmFKfWVqskKdgqGBsZ12oqVHMpAEFqcka@gqE1V@3//wA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @0stone0 I see no error on my machine, even with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: https://3v4l.org/KPdeK and for 7.2 there's really no errors.

Comment: It's just access of string/array with curly braces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP (up to version 7.4) still has syntax with which you can access elements of array with `{}` instead of `[]`, so your clause is just:

```
if (!true[false][false][323]) {
    echo 1;
}
```

And as you can see, nothing of this can be considered **true**. So you have

```
if (!NULL) {
    echo 1;
}
```

Which in turn outputs **1**.

In php8 such syntax is not supported and you will receive **Fatal error**:  https://3v4l.org/KPdeK

Comment: PHP 7.4 emits several deprecation errors, though. And frankly if I'd encounter such code, I would question the mental sanity of it's creator. It makes me feel like I am missing some hidden magic effect, which distracts from any other task I am on when reading that code - avoid such lines at all costs, change to something sensible that is doing the same in a more obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

The code works the same as this one:

```
<?php
if (!is_null(null)[1 == 2][false][$b = 323]) {
    echo 1;
}
```

It uses a deprecated feature of PHP, which is accessing arrays with curly braces (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access).

It works because there is a negation sign at the beginning and the rest of the statement evaluates to null, which is false.

Answer (score -2):

It works on version up-to 7.4 but it has been deprecated in PHP 8.

Comment: More a comment than an answer

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -3):

if($hh == $rr){$gg=$hh} else {$gg=$kg}

change ur code accor this format

Comment: why would the OP do that?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.